How can RemoteEvaluate use the existing WolframKernel service on the server?
Because the wstpserver(/usr/local/Wolfram/Wolfram/14.1/SystemFiles/Links/WSTPServer/wstpserver) process on my wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux, its ip is 172.23.90.252) is running by default.
systemctl status wstp


So RemoteEvaluate["wstp://172.23.90.252", $ProcessID] always return 758 or 428. As you can see from the image above, this is the pid of the existing process.
Now I have configure a SshKernels kernel like following:

I found that even though I already have a WolframKernel process on my wsl server, every time I run RemoteEvaluate["wsl", $ProcessID], I get a new process pid:
RemoteEvaluate["wsl", $ProcessID]


330287

That is, when running RemoteEvaluate["wsl", $ProcessID], each time a new WolframKernel process is generated to run the mma expression that RemoteEvaluate sends to the wsl server. This often consumes a lot of meaningless time. Is there any way to avoid this?

Is this not the same question as How to start a persistent process for RemoteEvaluate?
